# Proof of commutation relation for lattice QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, commutator, lattice-model, lattice-gauge-theory

How do you prove the following commutation relation for the lattice QFT

\begin{equation}
[\phi(X),\Pi(y)]=\text{i}a^{-d}\delta_{x,y}\mathbb{I}?
\end{equation}

Comment: I want to know how to derive the commutation relation from the functional-integral formulation of lattice QFT. Also, I would like to know why it is defined in this way in general? I want have a little more insight.

Comment: I mean give that eigenstates of momentum operator are Fourier transform of eigenstates field operator, it should be possible to show the commutation relation.

Comment: One shifts from a lattice discrete-time path integral picture to an operator picture by writing the partition function $Z$ as the trace of a transfer matrix $T$. To pass to the continuous-time Hamitonian picture you have a scale the couplings and the discrete time steps  so  that $T\to \exp\{-H \delta t\}$.

Comment: Can we prove this directly using Fourier transform?

Comment: is it possible to prove it using Fourier transform?

Comment: You never defined your symbols, and what is provided in your source. Deriving commutation relations from path integrals is unusual. Are you *sure* that's how your relation is stated to have been derived?